# Заменить &nbsp на <div class="ser">

Tags: jquery

Помогите пожулуйста, мне нужно заменить &nbsp на 
чтоб получилось

```
<div class="name">Коллекция</div><div class="ser">Серия ST</div>
```

сейчас это так

```
<div class="name">Коллекция&nbsp; Серия ST</div>
```

Comment: $('.name').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'<div class="ser">'));
});
так работает, но мне нужно чтоб закрывающий тег </div> еще работал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let test = '<div class="name">Коллекция&nbsp; Серия ST</div>'.replace('&nbsp;', '</div><div class="ser">');

console.log(test);
```

---

```js
let test = '<div class="name">Коллекция&nbsp; Серия ST</div>'.split('&nbsp;');
let newString = `${test[0].trim()}</div><div class="ser">${test[1].trim()}`;


console.log(newString);
```

---

```js
let test = '<div class="name">Коллекция&nbsp; Серия ST</div>';
let newString = test.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'</div><div class="ser">');


console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Отлично но текста Коллекция и серия ST меняются. единственное что остаеться это теги

Comment: вот как сделать чтоб с тегами только работало

Comment: @ВиталийМукменёв что? в смысле меняются? Ничего не меняется. Пруф в ответе, если кликнуть на "выполнить код"

Comment: <div class="property">
<div class="name">Яркость светового потока, Лм&nbsp; 400</div>
</div>
вот другое

Comment: <div class="property">
<div class="name">Тип лампы&nbsp; Светодиодная</div>
</div> и.тд

Comment: @ВиталийМукменёв и что там меняется? работает аналогично

Comment: у вас же только с Коллекция&nbsp; Серия ST

Comment: @ВиталийМукменёв так вы не просто копируйте код,  подставьте вместо одной строки другую.

Comment: @ВиталийМукменёв заносите текст в переменную и работаете уже с ней

Comment: $('.name').each(function(){ $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'<div class="ser">')); });
я так сделал, но закрывающего тега нет

Comment: и как сделать если нет тега &nbsp?Например если так
<div class="property">
<div class="name">Размеры H70 D45</div>
</div>

Comment: @ВиталийМукменёв делайте так: `'СТРОКА'.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'</div><div class="ser">')`